# How to get Infromation Link query from Spotfire Library Database

Tags: oracle, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I am new to Tibco Spotfire and I am working on a query to retrieve the query used by/generated by Spotfire while designing an information link.

I have access to the Library DB which saves the metadata of all the items/elements used in dashboards and stuff like that. I have been able to locate the information link items in the DB but I can't find the actual query that is used by the information link.

I need a solution that can be implemented from the DB, UI solutions are already in use and I am looking to automate that manual process of going to each info-link and clicking the "SQL" button in the Information Designer tool

so far I have come across [this link] (https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-find-the-manually-modified-SQL-query-used-by-a-particular-Information-Link) on Tibco's community forum but it doesn't show the autogenerated queries (only the manually modified queries).

Any and all help on this will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the SQL logs on the server.  Attempt to open the info link.  Then, log into the server.  Go to the folder where your spotfire installation is and find a folder that looks like this...

\Tibco\tss\10.3.6\tomcat\logs

...and you want the SQL.txt file.  Search for your user name.

Comment: Yes this will work for a single query at a time, but i was wondering if there is a way to get all the information link queries at once (like a select query on Library DB) as I need the information for further impact analysis

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  The queries are only registered when they are run and then logged....I think.